# Create new Thread for Private Sub DataGridView1_CellClick

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-code

Im trying to create a new thread for Private Sub, to make it run indepedently. Im unable to create a thread. Below is my code. Please suggest

```
Dim Thread_1 As System.Threading.Thread
Thread_1 = New System.Threading.Thread(AddressOf DataGridView1_CellClick)
Thread_1.Start()      

Private Sub DataGridView1_CellClick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellClick
    If e.ColumnIndex = 0 Then
        Me.DataGridView2.Rows.Add(DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(3).Value, "Co", "Speed", 75, DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(2).Value)
        'Script | PE/CE | LTP | Lots 
    End If

    If e.ColumnIndex = 1 Then 
        Me.DataGridView2.Rows.Add(DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(3).Value, "Co", "Mass", 75, DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(2).Value)
    End If

    If e.ColumnIndex = 5 Then
        Me.DataGridView2.Rows.Add(DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(3).Value, "Po", "Speed", 75, DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(4).Value)
    End If

    If e.ColumnIndex = 6 Then
        Me.DataGridView2.Rows.Add(DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(3).Value, "Po", "Mass", 75, DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(4).Value)
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: No, no, no. That is absolutely not how it works. When the user clicks a cell, the `CellClick` event is raised on the UI thread and your handler method is executed on the UI thread. You don't change that. If you have work to do that you want done on another thread, you put that code in its own method and then execute that method on another thread. Any data required from the grid for that work must be extracted from the grid on the UI thread first and any changes to be made to the grid at the end must be made on the UI thread too. That's how it works.

Comment: For the record, I don't see anything there that justifies even talking about multithreading, never mind trying to implement it.